# How do I stop CKEditor from stripping out Adsense Ads <ins> tag in my Django admin backend?

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor

I have implemented a standard CKEditor configuration on my Django site's admin backend. The default CKEDITOR_CONFIGS in settings.py is:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'allowedContent': True,
    },
}
```

In the article model I have:

```
description = RichTextField()
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to insert a Google Adsense Ad unit code in the CKEditor source and save it like so:

[image]

The CKEditor is stripping the ins tag from the Adsense ad code after saving as seen here:

[image]

How do I prevent the CKEditor from stripping the  tag from the Adsense code?

I have tried implementing the solution suggested here by adding the two lines to the CKEditor's config.js file but that doesn't have any effect:
[How to push a protectedSource in django-ckeditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940328/how-to-push-a-protectedsource-in-django-ckeditor)

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2019, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
    config.protectedSource.push( /<ins[\s|\S]+?<\/ins>/g );
    config.protectedSource.push( /<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"\>.*?<\/ins\>/g );
};
```

This leads to another question: how do I make sure that the CKEditor's config.js file is being applied as it seems its currently not being applied?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is pointing to your local CKEditor static files rather than your production:
`CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/'`

I also switched back to CKEditor 4 as 5 didn't work even after changing to the correct CKEDITOR_BASEPATH.